# Gulp : Passing Config.json to Build Taslk

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have created a config.json file and reading it in gulpfile.js

```
var config = require('./config.json')
```

How do I pass this config object to my tasks ?

My Project configuration :

app/gulpfile.js --> Read the JSON file here

```
var config = require('./config.json');
....
gulp.task('build',['scripts:build']);
```

My Task --> app/dev/gulp/scripts.js 
....
console.log(config)

StackTrace:

```
ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\app\dev\gulp\tasks\scripts.js:16:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at requireDir (D:\app\node_modules\require-dir\index.js:116:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\app\gulpfile.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Comment: require is synchrone, so you can use directly 'config' in your tasks.

Comment: "@PierreEmmanuelLallemant - its giving reference error when I access the variable from my tasks file

Comment: i'm not sure that your config.json is valid.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant - JSON is valid and I can print that in my gulpfile.js

Comment: 'scripts:build' is in another file ? if yes, you have to load the config in the module too. I don't think you can pass arguments to a task.

Comment: Hmm this is what I was hoping not to do .. Now if i have style task again i have to write the boilerplate code to load the json (Env Configs ) ..

Comment: You should write a config.js or bootstrap.js file to import, that will import the right config.json in all the files you write your tasks. By doing this, you only have to modify config.js to modify the file you load etc... (in config.js, export the require(__dirname + './config.json') ;